# Array.includes vs Array.prototype.includes

Tags: javascript, arrays

What's the difference between `Array.includes` and `Array.prototype.includes`?

Consider the following code:

```
var x = [1,2,3];
var arrayIncludes = Array.includes.bind(x);
var protoIncludes = Array.prototype.includes.bind(x);
```

Any call to arrayIncludes (e.g. `arrayIncludes(2)`) returns false.
Calls to protoIncludes return the correct result (e.g. `protoIncludes(2)` returns true).

Why is that? What's this special "includes" function on the Array object?

### Edit

I was looking at my site that has polyfills, sorry.

However, I am not sure any of the suggested duplicates are relevant.

Comment: `Array.includes` gives `undefined`. How your one works?

Comment: Seems like you have gone down some very strange path. Time to come back from there. None of this makes much sense

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Array_generic_methods

Answer (score 3):

`Array.prototype.includes` means `includes` is a method of Array prototype and it means that every **instance** of Array (e.g `x=[1, 2, 3]`) can invoke it. for example:

```
var x = [1, 2, 3];
x.includes(2);  // returns true
```

BUT Array class itself doesn't have the include method (this method is defined in its prototype, not the Array constructor) so Array doesn't have this method to call it later.

```
console.log(Array.includes);  // prints undefined
```